# error -2147467259 (80004005) .net mdb

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-access, mdb2

I am calling a vb.net function of a dll from below VBA code in MDB.
I am calling Get_GDW_data_final sub from immediate Window.

```
Public Sub Get_GDW_data_final()
Dim r As New Get_GDW_Data.GDW
MsgBox r.DetailedWork()
End Sub
```

I have created Get_GDW_Data.dll added reference of it in MDB.

The coding of class is as below.

```
Public Class GDW
    Public Function DetailedWork()
        Dim lastrow As Long
        Dim ADODBcnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Access8\W156_RocketOffset_Backup.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;Mode=read")
        Dim ADODBcmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim ADODBcmd1 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim ADODBrst As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        ADODBcnn.Open()
        ADODBcmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from input"
        lastrow = ADODBcmd.ExecuteScalar()
        ADODBcnn.Close()
        Return lastrow.ToString()

    End Function
End Class
```

Here I am getting error

Run-time Error -2147467259 (80004005)
The database has been put in a state by admin or machine 'Rachit' that prvents it from being opened or locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered what the problem was:

It's a Limitation of Access that you can not access a table of a database using a dll from which you are calling the function :-)

Answer (score 0):

`INPUT` is a reserved word, so try:

```
ADODBcmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from [input]"
```

Comment: Yes I did that already but That is not the reason of that error.

The issue is the database is already open and I am calling sub from the immediate window which calls a .net function which tries to access table of the database which is already open.

kind of simultaneous connectin issue.